# How do I access Layout object in Zend Framework plugin?

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, zend-layout

I am trying to use a layout for each actions in a controller. For example, I have three actions in index controller. Those are indexAction, testAction, and welcomeAction. I created three xml layout files. index.xml, test.xml, and welcome.xml. Finally, I created a plugin.

```
class Moon_Layout_Append extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract{

 public function preDispatch($request){


  $layoutFile = APPLICATION_PATH."/Modules/".$request->module."/layout/".$request->action.".xml";

  $layout = new Zend_Config_Xml($layoutFile,'index');


 }

}
```

the problem is...how do I access layout object to set content that I read from xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Layout functionality is easily accessed via a Controller Action helper. You should be able to retrieve the layout helper using the following line.

```
$layout= Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Layout');
```

If you're not using the Zend_Application or another way of initialising the Layout, you may need to call the following first:

```
Zend_Layout::startMvc();
```

Comment: if I $layout->header = "test"; and call it in a layout file by $this->layout()->header, it does not show anything. Do you know why?

Comment: Try $view = $layout->getView(); $view->header = 'test'; and then echo $this->header in your layout.

Comment: dcaunt // thanks!! $view->layout()->header = "test"; works!! thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial tell exactly what you need, you can create a xml for navigation and display this in your layout.phtml

http://www.goodcomputingtips.com/site/2010/09/part-5-adding-menus-using-zend_navigation-a-not-so-quick-quickstart-to-zend-framework/

A quick example:

> In your bootstrap

```
protected function _initNavigation() {
$this->bootstrap("layout");
$layout = $this->getResource('layout');     
$view = $layout->getView();

$config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml','nav');
$navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);

$view->navigation($navigation); }
```

> In your layout.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setMaxDepth(1); ?>
```

In the link you have other ways to configure.

Answer (score 1):

For me worked only

```
$layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
```

and

```
 $layout= Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Layout');
```

didn't work.